# How to change the icon color selected on bottom navigation bar in android studio

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

When I select an item in bottom navigation bar in android studio, background item selected is equal to primarycolor in values->colors.xml . and now I want to change this color which is not to same the primarycolor. how do i can to change it?

```
    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        Fragment fragment;
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fragment = new HomeFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_addpost:
                    fragment = new AddFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
//                    mTextMessage.setText(R.string.title_notifications);
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_profile:
                    fragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    loadFragment(fragment);
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        loadFragment(new HomeFragment());
        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
        navigation.setItemTextColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
    }
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To change the selected tab icon color in `BottomNavigationView` you should use the Selector.

Create `bottom_navigation_selector.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/yourSelectedColor" />
  <item android:color="@color/defaultColor"  />
</selector>
```

Apply `app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"` to your BottomNavigationView in `xml` file.

Comment: It's my pleasure. Happy coding !!

Comment: I know this is old, but how do you change the text colour too?

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: Not working. Please help. I am using contraintlayout as my parent.

Comment: I cant apply a drawable to itemIconTint. Only a color

Comment: @MikkelT Just add `bottom_navigation_selector.xml` to your `color` folder in `res`.

Comment: This solution still helpful. Thanks @ChandanSharma.

Answer (score 15):

Despite reading all the answers I was confused about whole process, so I am going to explain step by step how I resolved this issue so beginners can understand it properly

Let's assume you created bottom navigation activity with name `MainActivity` so now

create `bottom_navigation_selector.xml` in your `drawable` folder using this code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/yourSelectedColor" />
  <item android:color="@color/defaultColor"  />
</selector>
```

then go to the `activity_main.xml` layout and add this line in `BottomNavigationView`

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
```

If you also want to change text color accordingly then you need to add this line aswell

```
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_selector"
```

Answer (score 2):

To show the real color of items use this

**java**

```
bottom_navigation.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

**kotlin**

```
bottom_navigation.itemIconTintList = null
```

and if you want to change the calor just replace the null with

```
Color.parseColor("#ffffff")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
navigation.setItemIconTintList(Color.BLUE);
```

Update :

```
navigation.setItemIconTintList(Color.parseColor("#fafafa"));
```

Comment: Ok . Now changed the icon color . but i want to change the color selected icon of blue to another color

Comment: Give whatever color you want as parameter to function.

Comment: The icon color is black and i want to change #fafafa when selected

Answer (score 0):

If you are using compose and constructing a **BottomNavigationItem** you have to use the u*nselectedContentColor* option to set the color.

eg

```kotlin
unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
```

```
   BottomNavigationItem(
                icon = {},
                unselectedContentColor = MaterialTheme.colors.primary,
                alwaysShowLabel = false,
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = { },
            )
```

Answer (score -1):

```
bottomNavigationView.setItemIconTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5")));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the problem the answer would be a lot better with an explanation on how/why it does.  Remember that your answer is not just for the user that asked the question but also for all the other people that find it.