# How to set text color of bottom navigation item selection and unselection?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I was trying to set the following attribute of BottomNavigationView widget

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/text_color"
```

But this sets the text color of active and inactive item both. I want to have different text color on active and inactive item of BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have to make a selectable color in `res>color>selectable_color`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/selected_text_color" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:color="@color/unselected_text_color"/>
</selector>
```

Then you have to set this selectable color as `itemTextColor` in `BottomNavigationView` widget

```
app:itemTextColor="@color/selectable_text_color"
```

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain Can I know why you edited this and what mistake you found? How can you add a `Drawable` resource file to the `Color` resource file?

Comment: @MDev because it is color selector not a drawable selector

Comment: @MDev attribute of BottomNavigationView requires a color file not a drawable file. Kindly give it a try you'll be clear

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain @BeeDeveloper I don't know why you all adding `Selector` in the `color resource`? checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51580222/16765223

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain and checkout this also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503475/16765223

Comment: @MDev text selector is created in the color directory in the resource directory not in the color file because the itemTextColor requires color not drawable.

Comment: @SyedRafaqatHussain I already used this code to change my text and item color. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65503475/16765223